# Delete all negative nodes from linked list and get sum of nodes from linked list in python

Tags: python, linked-list, sum

def delete_negative and sumOfNode are both broken and I'm unsure of how to fix them.
delete_negative is supposed to go through the linked list and delete any negative numbers.
sumOfNode is supposed to return the sum of all values in the linked list.

Could someone please walk me through this?

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.count=0

    def insertEnd(self, newNode):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=newNode
        else:
            lastNode=self.head
            while True:
                if lastNode.next is None:
                    break
                lastNode=lastNode.next
            lastNode.next=newNode

    def insertHead(self, newNode):
        tempNode = self.head
        self.head = newNode         
        self.head.next = tempNode        
        #del tempNode

    def delete_negative(self):
        temp = self.head
        self.head = self.head.next
        if self.head < 0:
            temp = None

    def sumOfNode(self): 
        while self.head != None:
            temp = self.head
            yield self.head.data
            self.head = self.head.next

        return sum(sumOfNode())
      
FirstNode=Node(2)
mylist=linked_list()
mylist.insertEnd(FirstNode)

SecondNode=Node(3)
mylist.insertEnd(SecondNode)

ThirdNode=Node(4)
mylist.insertEnd(ThirdNode)

FourthNode=Node(1)
mylist.insertHead(FourthNode)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Always make a display function to view your linked list. It helps you debug.
Never ever modify your head pointer. It is the only point of reference to your linked list. Use a temp variable to traverse through the list.

While deleting negative values from the list, there are 2 cases:

1. The head value is negative
2. Other values are negative

Each has to be handled differently.

Your choice of using a generator function for sum of values was wise. But implementation was a bit off.

```
class Node:
    def __init__(self,data):
        self.data = data
        self.next = None
        
class linked_list:
    def __init__(self):
        self.head=None
        self.count=0

    def insertEnd(self, newNode):
        if self.head is None:
            self.head=newNode
        else:
            lastNode=self.head
            while True:
                if lastNode.next is None:
                    break
                lastNode=lastNode.next
            lastNode.next=newNode

    def insertHead(self, newNode):
        tempNode = self.head
        self.head = newNode         
        self.head.next = tempNode        
        #del tempNode

    def delete_negative(self):
        temp = self.head
        prev = None
        while temp:
            if temp.data < 0:
                if temp == self.head:
                    self.head = temp.next
                    temp = self.head
                else:
                    prev.next = temp.next
                    temp = temp.next
            else:
                prev = temp
                temp = temp.next

    def sumOfNode(self):
        temp = self.head
        def get_sum(temp):
            while temp:
                yield temp.data
                temp = temp.next
        return sum(get_sum(temp))
    
    def display(self):
        temp = self.head
        while temp:
            print(temp.data)
            temp = temp.next
      
FirstNode=Node(2)
mylist=linked_list()
mylist.insertEnd(FirstNode)

SecondNode=Node(-3)
mylist.insertEnd(SecondNode)

ThirdNode=Node(4)
mylist.insertEnd(ThirdNode)

FourthNode=Node(1)
mylist.insertHead(FourthNode)
mylist.display()
print("Sum=",mylist.sumOfNode())
mylist.delete_negative()
mylist.display()
```